# Simple rule appears not to work

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, rule

I have the following simple code

```
Clear["Global`*"];

V = v0^2/2*Log[x^2 + (y/q)^2 + rc^2];
sub = {(v0^2/(x^2 + (y/q)^2 + rc^2)) -> (arg)};

Vx = D[V, x];
Vy = D[V, y];

Vxx = Simplify[D[V, {x, 2}]];
Vxy = Simplify[D[Vx, y]];
Vyy = Simplify[D[V, {y, 2}]];
Vyx = Simplify[D[Vy, x]];

Print["******************************"]
Print["Vx = ", Vx //. sub]
Print["Vy = ", Vy //. sub]
Print["Vxx = ", Vxx //. sub]
Print["Vxy = ", Vxy //. sub]
Print["Vyx = ", Vyx //. sub]
Print["Vyy = ", Vyy //. sub]
Print["*****************************"]
```

which calculates the first and second derivatives the function $V$. The printed results I added a rule `sub` in order to make the output much simpler. However, for a strange reason, the rule applies correctly to the first derivatives $Vx$ and $Vy$ but it has no effect to the second ones $(Vxx, Vxy, Vyx, Vyy)$. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, because rules apply to the `FullForm` of an expression. If the `FullForm` does not match then nothing will be replaced. The pattern you use for the replacement is pretty complicated so it is not very surprising that it only matches in a few special cases. Rewrite your rule such that the left hand side is simpler and try again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the best ways to diagnose pattern matching problems is look at the `FullForm` or `TreeForm` of the left-hand side of the pattern as well as the object you are attempting to match:

```
sub[[1, 1]] // TreeForm
```

[image]

```
Vxx // TreeForm
```

[image]

For the pattern to match the structure must be the same (or appear within the structure), and as you can see they are very different.

---

For the mathematical transformation I believe you are attempting these related questions may be helpful:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/replacing-term-by-variable-with-mathematica/11701#11701